# textbox character countdown asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax

i have many textboxes on a form and all textboxes require to have a character limit / character countdown (50 character left of 150), what is the best way to achieve this and can anyone please provide code to implement.

Much Grateful

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple raw ones: 
http://www.smartwebby.com/DHTML/textbox_characters_counter.asp
http://www.reconn.us/character_counter.html

and one for jquery as a plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/360