# How to count number of character which is entered in textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a label `lblCountCharacter` with text "4000" and a textbox `txtAddNote` where users can enter text.

On entering one character in `txtAddNote`, the label text is decreased by one.

Please help me write a function for this in asp.net using C#.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449928/textbox-character-countdown-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get a better solution to this by using just javascript/jQuery. Using c# is going to involve having to use AJAX to re-render the Label each time.

```
var characterLimit = 4000
var charLeft = characterLimit - $(".textbox").val().length
$(".label").html(charLeft);
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to avoid post backs you can use jQuery to determine the length of the text in the text box:

```
var myLength = $("#myTextbox").val().length;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update a label with the remaining character count, you would want to use a javascript function. You can add an event handler for a key press on the textbox that updates the text of the label.

You can find more information about capturing the key presses in a textbox [here](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial138_Get-key-press-event-using-JavaScript.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use javascript to do this.
in the onkeypress event call a javascript function which will check the length of the content of text box and then update the label in the form.